# Mongo Query with Compound Indexes Still Scans All Documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having troubles getting a query to run in a reasonable amount of time.  The collection I'm working with is ~100M documents.  When I run the currentOp() command to check out the query, it seems to be scanning all documents.

```
db.collection.find({
    "field_1": {"$not": /^Some_Regex/},
    "field_2": "value_1",
    "timestamp_field": {"$gte": ISODate("2016-12-01T00:00:00.000+0000")}
}).sort({"field_1": 1})
```

I am passing in the hint of:

```
{"field_1": 1, "timestamp_field": -1}
```

My understanding of how the compound index works is that it creates a table:

```
field_1     timestamp_field
a           2016-12-03 00:00:00
a           2016-12-02 00:00:00
a           2016-12-01 00:00:00
a           2016-11-30 00:00:00
a           2016-12-29 00:00:00
```

Now it should be able to filter out any documents where the requirements for `field_1` and `timestamp_field` don't match.  I would expect that this query would only have to scan at maximum, the result from this query:

```
db.collection.count({
    "field_1": {"$not": /^Regex/},
    "timestamp_field": {"$gte": ISODate("2016-12-01T00:00:00.000+0000")}
}).sort({"field_1": 1})
```

Should I be using an index on three fields?  Should I be using a different index?  There's over 50M actions where `{"field_2": "value_1"}`, which is why I chose to create the compound index on the other two fields.

Any help into why this query is so slow would be appreciated.

Comment: `$not` cannot use index, even if you do prefix regex match. Change your regex so the NOT is inside the regex, so basically you are saying what you want `field_1` to be, rather than what it should not be.

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue when I remove that entire part from the query.

Comment: To use the index you need to specify both fields. If you remove the condition on `field_1` then it can't use the index. On compound indexes, you need to specify all the initial fields for the index to be used.